# Detect change of focus inside of one frame

Tags: tkinter, focus

I want to detect if the focus "jumps" from one (e.g.) `Entry` to another one that is also mapped inside the same `Frame`. I know that you can detect if focus gets from any widget mapped outside of the `Frame` onto a widget inside the `Frame` by binding `'<FocusIn>` to the `Frame`. But from what I tried this doesn't work for what I want since focus doesn't get to the `Frame`.

I had the Idea to just use `bind_all` but that would be generating unneccesary events since on focusing one widget every master widget, masters master widget, etc. would create such a event.

Another way I thought of is binding `'<Configure>'` to the `Frame` with a callback that checks for every child if it has focus bound to it and if not binds it so that I get a `'<FocusIn>'` event from that child later on. But there are two flaws I see there too:

1. Placing something with `Widget.place` won't be detected since it shouldn't configure the size, position or borders of it's parent.
2. I would need to manage which widgets I bound `'<FocusIn>'` to and which not. A bit overkill imo.

Is there any smoother/better way that I could do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ***binding `<FocusIn>` to the `Frame`***: You have to bind to the `Entry` instead. Why do you need this event?

Comment: Binding to the ```Entry``` would be an option as described in my second idea. But that would again mean that I need to find every Entry that will eventually get mapped on that Frame.
I need this Event to be able to move a focused Widget into sight, meaning getting the coords of the focused widget on the ```Frame``` and placing the Frame according on it's parent.

Comment: The problem with ```for child in frame.children:``` (```children``` isn't a method ^^) is that you don't get ```Entry```s that are mapped on a ```Frame``` on this ```Frame``` if you can follow me here. I would need to find ALL children (at least to a certain degree) which gets massive quite fast. And the second problem with that is: What do I do when more children get added? I need to handle that too since they can get focused too. And yes I use ```place```.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand completely what you mean there. Could you provide a small example as an answer for me, please? ^^

Comment: Something like [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/OvercookedDifferentAddress)

Comment: Hm I see what you did there. I might have been unclear about that `Entry` was just an example. Furthermore I didn't wanted to restrict the way to map something on there to just `grid`. Anyway I think I'll just take a different approach and make a user need to "register" whatever can get into focus. Still, thank you for your efforts.